# SignalR with react native app and c# website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react-native, signalr

Is there any way to connect signalR to my React native app
Previously I had a web version in ASP .net and in that I had implemented SignalR.
But now we have to develop a react native App and also integrate chat in it.
So is there any way to connect with the same server and methods in the App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good library to connect signar hub with react-native.

https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr

Only issue is that its not updated in a long time. we use this in our app and it works as expected.

Comment: Can you please let me know for solution that it call message receive method for two times
 `proxy.on("messageReceived", (msg) => {
      console.log("message-from-server", msg);
    });`

Comment: Only issue that i can think is that subscribing twice other than that I've never go this issue